# Simple Gallery Slider

Tags: slider

I'm trying to create a simple slider using divs and javascript. I set up a div with six images and an arrow that movies the containder holding the images 528px (the width of each image) every time it's clicked. When I reach the begining or end of the gallery, I want the respective arrow button to fade out so that the user won't keep pressing next/prev.

Any help is appreciated.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#btn-gallery-next").click(function(){
$("div#gallery li").not(this).removeClass('clicked');
$("div#gallery-slide").animate({left:"-=528px"});
if($("div#gallery-slide").position().left < -3168)
{
    $("#btn-gallery-next").fadeOut();
}
else {
    $("#btn-gallery-next").fadeIn();
}

});

$("#btn-gallery-prev").click(function(){
$("div#gallery li").not(this).removeClass('clicked');
$("div#gallery-slide").animate({left:"+=528px"});
if($("div#gallery-slide").position().left > 0)
{
    $("#btn-gallery-prev").fadeOut();
}
else {
    $("#btn-gallery-prev").fadeIn();
}

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="gallery-slide">
      <img class="gallery-img" src="_/img/gallery/img1.jpg" alt="" />
      <img class="gallery-img" src="_/img/gallery/img2.jpg" alt="" />
      <img class="gallery-img" src="_/img/gallery/img3.jpg" alt="" />
      <img class="gallery-img" src="_/img/gallery/img4.jpg" alt="" />
      <img class="gallery-img" src="_/img/gallery/img5.jpg" alt="" />
      <img class="gallery-img" src="_/img/gallery/img6.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [flex slider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) from woothemes, it have all ur needs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a slider library like [Owl Slider](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)? It comes with lots of options and configurations. It is super simple to integrate into any project.

- Example #1 www.midwestgathering.com/#galleries
- Example #2 www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html

Another option is [jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/basic/). The basic slider is shown with an example that makes the left next button inactive until the user slides to the right, then once the user gets to the end of the gallery the right next button becomes inactive:

**JS**

```
(function($) {
$(function() {
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel();

    $('.jcarousel-control-prev')
        .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('inactive');
        })
        .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
            $(this).addClass('inactive');
        })
        .jcarouselControl({
            target: '-=1'
        });

    $('.jcarousel-control-next')
        .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('inactive');
        })
        .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function() {
            $(this).addClass('inactive');
        })
        .jcarouselControl({
            target: '+=1'
        });

    $('.jcarousel-pagination')
        .on('jcarouselpagination:active', 'a', function() {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        })
        .on('jcarouselpagination:inactive', 'a', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        .jcarouselPagination();
});
})(jQuery);
```

**CSS**

```
.jcarousel-wrapper {
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
  }


.jcarousel-wrapper .photo-credits {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    opacity: .66;
}

.jcarousel-wrapper .photo-credits a {
    color: #fff;
}

/** Carousel **/

.jcarousel {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}

.jcarousel ul {
    width: 20000em;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.jcarousel li {
    float: left;
}

/** Carousel Controls **/

.jcarousel-control-prev,
.jcarousel-control-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #4E443C;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
    font: 24px/27px Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
}

.jcarousel-control-prev {
    left: -50px;
}

.jcarousel-control-next {
    right: -50px;
}

.jcarousel-control-prev:hover span,
.jcarousel-control-next:hover span {
    display: block;
}

.jcarousel-control-prev.inactive,
.jcarousel-control-next.inactive {
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: default;
}

/** Carousel Pagination **/

.jcarousel-pagination {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15px;
}

.jcarousel-pagination a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;

    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
    min-width: 14px;

    background: #fff;
    color: #4E443C;
    border-radius: 14px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;

    margin-right: 2px;

    opacity: .75;
}

.jcarousel-pagination a.active {
    background: #4E443C;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

You can find documentation for jcarousel at www.sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/.

Answer (score 0):

see demo - **http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/waKju?editors=011**

### javascript

```
/**
* Slider - loops over images
* SEP 2014
* By - Yair Even-Or
*/
var Slider = function(elm, prev, next){
    var that = this;
    this.locked = false;
    this.slider = elm;
    this.children = this.slider.children;
    this.itemWidth = this.children[0].clientWidth;

    this.preloadImages();

    next && next.addEventListener('click', function(){ that.move('next') });
    prev && prev.addEventListener('click', function(){ that.move('prev') });
}

Slider.prototype = { 
    move : function(dir){
        var that = this, 
            itemToMove;

        if( this.locked ){ 
            this.locked.removeAttribute('style');
            this.slider.appendChild(this.locked);
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
            moveToEnd();
        }

        // do nothing if there are no items
        if( this.children.length < 2 )
            return false;

        itemToMove = this.children[0];
        this.locked = itemToMove;

        if( dir == 'next' )
            itemToMove.style.marginLeft = -this.itemWidth + 'px';
        else{
            itemToMove = this.children[this.children.length-1];
            itemToMove.style.marginLeft = -this.itemWidth + 'px';
            this.slider.insertBefore(itemToMove, this.children[0]);
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                itemToMove.removeAttribute('style');
            },50);
            this.preloadImages();
            this.locked = false;
        }

        // move the child to the end of the items' list
        if( dir == 'next' )
            this.timer = setTimeout(moveToEnd, 420);

        function moveToEnd(el){
            itemToMove = el || itemToMove;
            if( !itemToMove ) return;
            itemToMove.removeAttribute('style');
            that.slider.appendChild(itemToMove);
            that.locked = false;
            that.preloadImages();
        }
    },
    preloadImages : function(){
      this.lazyload(this.children[1].getElementsByTagName('img')[0] );
      this.lazyload(this.children[this.children.length-1].getElementsByTagName('img')[0] );
    },
    // lazy load image
    lazyload : function(img){
        var lazy = img.getAttribute('data-src');
        if( lazy ){
            img.src = lazy;
            img.removeAttribute('data-src');
        }
    }
}




// HOW TO USE /////////////////
var sliderElm = document.querySelector('.content'),
    next = document.querySelector('.next'),
    prev = document.querySelector('.prev'),
    slider = new Slider(sliderElm, prev, next);
```

### HTML (JADE syntax)

```
.slider
    a.arrow.next
    a.arrow.prev
    ul.content
        li
            img(src='image1.jpg')
        li
            img(src='image2.jpg')
        li
            img(src='image3.jpg')
        li
            img(src='image4.jpg')
```